# BPEL. Add wsse security header to invoke method(not with Oracle BPEL)

Tags: bpel

I am trying to invoke a web service that has wsse security enabled. I do not use oracle BPEL. My tools are eclipse and apache ode. Is there any specific way to do it? Below you can find the section that I want to add to the security header

```
<wsse:Security> 
<wsse:UsernameToken>               
    <wsse:Username>MyUsername</wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password Type="PasswordText">MyPassword</wsse:Password>
 </wsse:UsernameToken>
```